# How to change the button text on click for a short duration only using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a shopping cart website and I want my **Add to Cart** button to say **Item added** upon clicking it, but only for like 2 seconds then it changes back to **Add to Cart** . How do I do achieve this?

Comment: Use setTimeOut in javascript

Comment: What should occur if button element is clicked again before two seconds has elapsed since first click?

Answer (score 4):

In plain Javascript, you could use a variable for checking if the button is clicked and if not, set the button to the wanted string and change it back after two seconds.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function (clicked) {
    return function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            var last = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = 'Item added';
            clicked = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.innerHTML = last;
                clicked = false;
            }.bind(this), 2000);
        }
    };
}(false), this);
```

```html
<button id="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('button.add').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (!self.data('add')) {
        self.data('add', true);
        self.text('Item added');
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.text('Add to Cart').data('add', false);
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is result if button element is clicked multiple times within two seconds?

Comment: @guest271314 added condition that prevent double executing.

Answer (score 0):

1. In 'Add To Cart' event handler change the button text to 'Item Added'
2. In the same event handler use:  setTimeout(makeTimeoutFunc(), 2000);
3. In makeTimeoutFunc() change the button text to original value.

Answer (score 0):

After click, button text will be changed and the button will also be disabled to prevent further actions, then reverted back after two seconds.

```js
(function() {
  $(".btn-addcart").on("click", function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        oldText = $this.text();

    $this.text("Item added");
    $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.text(oldText);
      $this.removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 2000);

  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-addcart">Add to cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<input type="button" id="btn"/>

$("#btn").click(function(){
$(this).val("Item Added");
setTimeout(function(){ $("#btn").val("Add to Cart"); }, 2000);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with only javascript, without jquery.

```
<body>
  <input id ="button" type="button" value="add to cart" onclick=" tick(button)">
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

  function tick(button){
    document.getElementById("button").value = "Item added";
    setTimeout(() => (document.getElementById("button").value  = "add to cart"), 2000);
  }

</script>
```