# How to ensure javascript event runs second time?

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I have a button that when clicked, displays a message 'Copied!'. I've created a `.hidden` class and I'm using the `classList` property and `add()` method to apply it to the message. The hidden class contains a transition that fades the element out.

Currently, once the event runs, I can't get it to run again. The 'Copied!' message doesn't come up on a second click.

```js
copied.addEventListener("click", function () {
    copiedMsg.textContent = "Copied!";
    copiedMsg.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

button.btn {
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.primary {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn primary" id="copied"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Copy Snippet!</button> <span id="copiedMsg"></span>
```

Comment: May be you should add copiedMsg.classList.remove("hidden"); to the beginning of eventListener.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replay this CSS animation each time a user clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159123/how-to-replay-this-css-animation-each-time-a-user-clicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added in the line:

```
copiedMsg.classList.remove("hidden");
```

and added a `timeout` to run the code.

```js
copied.addEventListener("click", function() {
  copiedMsg.classList.remove("hidden");
  setTimeout(function() {
    copiedMsg.textContent = "Copied!";
    copiedMsg.classList.add("hidden");
  }, 10)
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

button.btn {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.primary {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn primary" id="copied"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Copy Snippet!</button> <span id="copiedMsg"></span>
```

**Explanation:**

```
copiedMsg.classList.remove("hidden");
```

This removes the class `hidden` if it contains it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  copiedMsg.textContent = "Copied!";
  copiedMsg.classList.add("hidden");
}, 10)
```

I wait one millisecond before I run the code, using the above line of code. I found that it didn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
copied.addEventListener("click", function () {
    copiedMsg.textContent = "Copied!";
    copiedMsg.classList.add("hidden");
    setTimeout(function() {
        copiedMsg.textContent = "";
        copiedMsg.classList.remove("hidden");
    }, 2000);// equal to 2s in your animation
});
```

Comment: This is the almost exact same thing that I have entered in my answer.

Comment: yeah we parallelly submitted similar answer

Comment: yeah funny they were submitted almost at the same time.

Comment: They were a minute apart. I had to look at the history to make sure I selected the right answer. But, @ManikantaReddy - I did upvote yours.

Comment: Thanks @JaredNewnam, we are here to improve skills, doesn't matter my answer marked are not... cheers

Answer (score 0):

You hide the span and then you never make it visible again. Try to remove hidden class first and fire the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take using the [Animation web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/finished). Despite what it says in MDN, it seems to run on chrome. That being said, likely not the best depending on the browsers you want to support.

This just loops over all the animations the element may have, and then removes the class after they all end.

```js
copied.addEventListener("click", function() {
  copiedMsg.textContent = "Copied!";
  copiedMsg.classList.add("hidden");
  Promise.all(copiedMsg.getAnimations().map(animation => animation.finished)).then(() => {
    copiedMsg.textContent = '';
    copiedMsg.classList.remove('hidden');

  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

button.btn {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.primary {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn primary" id="copied"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Copy Snippet!</button> <span id="copiedMsg"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with classList.add since in every event same class is added try toggle or something.